# How to specify htaccess rule for full string?

Tags: .htaccess

Currently i have rule as below for domain `domain.com` :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/abc/qa/1 https://linkof1.com
```

Above rule redirects `domain.com/abc/qa/1` to `https://linkof1.com`

**How to specify rewrite rule for `domain.com/abc/qa/10` to `https://linkof10.com`**

*Actually tried i have tried :*

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/abc/qa/10 https://linkof10.com
```

but this is redirecting to `https://linkof1.com`

other rules already in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Could you please post from which url to which url you want to redirect? That will give us better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: hope now its clear

Comment: Ok, so do you have any other rules too in your htaccess file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it like this:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^abc/qa/10/?$ https://linkof10.com [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^abc/qa/1/?$ https://linkof1.com [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please clear browser cache before testing your URLs. Also if in case you have already existing rules for non existing directories and files then keep these above them.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ON
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ abc/qa/10 [L]
```